# Cannot Load From HDF Data Store

Tags: python, pandas, hdfs

I am using pandas 0.11.0 on Windows 64 Bit.

I have a datastore:

```
store = pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore( r"""C:\data.h5""" )
```

It has some data in it:

```
print(store)
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: C:\data.h5

/region                           frame        (shape->[30,2])     
/sector                           frame        (shape->[116,2])
```

When I try to load 'sector' from the store I get:

```
store['/sector']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-7fea069742ed> in <module>()
----> 1 store['/sector']

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
    236 
    237     def __getitem__(self, key):
--> 238         return self.get(key)
    239 
    240     def __setitem__(self, key, value):

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.pyc in get(self, key)
    369         if group is None:
    370             raise KeyError('No object named %s in the file' % key)
--> 371         return self._read_group(group)
    372 
    373     def select(self, key, where=None, start=None, stop=None, columns=None, iterator=False, chunksize=None, **kwargs):

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.pyc in _read_group(self, group, **kwargs)
    876         s = self._create_storer(group)
    877         s.infer_axes()
--> 878         return s.read(**kwargs)
    879 
    880 class TableIterator(object):

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.pyc in read(self, **kwargs)
   1982         blocks = []
   1983         for i in range(self.nblocks):
-> 1984             blk_items = self.read_index('block%d_items' % i)
   1985             values = self.read_array('block%d_values' % i)
   1986             blk = make_block(values, blk_items, items)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.pyc in read_index(self, key)
   1615             return self.read_sparse_intindex(key)
   1616         elif variety == 'regular':
-> 1617             _, index = self.read_index_node(getattr(self.group, key))
   1618             return index
   1619         else:  # pragma: no cover

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.pyc in read_index_node(self, node)
   1733                             **kwargs)
   1734         else:
-> 1735             index = factory(_unconvert_index(data, kind), **kwargs)
   1736 
   1737         index.name = name

TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'freq'
```

What is this "freq" argument? And why is it stopping me from loading the data?

Comment: It looks for me that 'freq' in index is not exists. Have you check out those links? https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3499#issuecomment-17262905 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311045/in-pandas-why-is-frequency-information-lost-when-storing-in-hdf5-as-a-table

Comment: you have a fairly old pandas version and are reading a more current store. pls update to at least pandas 0.14.1.